# Infinite scroll on table with merged cells (defined colspan/rowspan)

Tags: javascript, html, css, pivot-table, olap

How can I implement the infinite scroll on a table with the merged cells?

I want to implement pivot grid with lots of data to be processed. The difficulty is drawing only visible parts of headers (+ scrolling buffer).

Possible solutions:

1. Without smooth scrolling, discretely, redraw all table header. (I would like smoothness)
2. Implement the div-table and organize creating and deleting items on scroll event. (Could not find an example of a dynamic div-table with the merged cells)
3. Implement the table header from the sequence of tables, that created and removed as necessary. (delete borders, share labels between the nearby tables)
   Example:

```js
var xHeaderWrapperEl = document.querySelector(".header-wrapper");
var xHeaderTableEl = document.querySelector(".header-table");

xHeaderWrapperEl.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    if (xHeaderWrapperEl.scrollLeft >= xHeaderTableEl.offsetWidth - xHeaderWrapperEl.offsetWidth){
        console.log("scroll next page");
    } else if (xHeaderWrapperEl.scrollLeft <= 0) {
        console.log("scroll prev page");
    } else {
        console.log("scroll");
    }
});
```

```css
.header-wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    //flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <!-- 1st block -->
        <table class="header-table" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="10"><div>0x1</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><div>1x1</div></td>
                <td colspan="8" rowspan="2"><div>1x2</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><div>2x1</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div>3x1</div></td>
                <td><div>3x2</div></td>
                <td><div>3x3</div></td>
                <td><div>3x4</div></td>
                <td><div>3x5</div></td>
                <td><div>3x6</div></td>
                <td><div>3x7</div></td>
                <td><div>3x8</div></td>
                <td><div>3x9</div></td>
                <td><div>3x10</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- 2nd block -->
        <table class="header-table" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><div>0x1</div></td>
                <td colspan="6"><div>0x2</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" rowspan="2"><div>1x1</div></td>
                <td colspan="6"><div>1x2</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"><div>2x1</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div>3x1</div></td>
                <td><div>3x2</div></td>
                <td><div>3x3</div></td>
                <td><div>3x4</div></td>
                <td><div>3x5</div></td>
                <td><div>3x6</div></td>
                <td><div>3x7</div></td>
                <td><div>3x8</div></td>
                <td><div>3x9</div></td>
                <td><div>3x10</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- 3rd block -->
        <table class="header-table" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><div>0x1</div></td>
                <td colspan="6"><div>0x2</div></td>
                <td colspan="2"><div>0x3</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><div>1x1</div></td>
                <td colspan="2"><div>1x2</div></td>
                <td colspan="2"><div>1x3</div></td>
                <td colspan="2"><div>1x4</div></td>
                <td colspan="2"><div>1x5</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><div>2x1</div></td>
                <td colspan="2"><div>2x2</div></td>
                <td colspan="2"><div>2x3</div></td>
                <td colspan="2"><div>2x4</div></td>
                <td colspan="2"><div>2x5</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div>3x1</div></td>
                <td><div>3x2</div></td>
                <td><div>3x3</div></td>
                <td><div>3x4</div></td>
                <td><div>3x5</div></td>
                <td><div>3x6</div></td>
                <td><div>3x7</div></td>
                <td><div>3x8</div></td>
                <td><div>3x9</div></td>
                <td><div>3x10</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>        
    </div>
</body>
```

4. Take note flexbox...

Comment: If in principle you can split your table into smaller ones then approach #3 looks better. As of scrolling... Do you need exactly infinite scrolling or you will have scrollbars in some form?

Comment: @c-smile Yep, scroll doesn't infinite, but table very huge. May be about dozen of millions cells. #3 has its difficulties associated with the merging of related tables.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you will have 1mln columns table according to your answer.

It is not realistic to have such a table continuously scrollable. 
It will take forever to scroll/find/consume information from there.

Therefore you have to have some pagination / filtering mechanism there. 
And with the pagination your problem is less severe. Split it in partial table blocks wrapped in scrollable page container. So you will have scrollable pages similar to gmail's message list - paginated yet scrollable.

Comment: Pagination is worse, because of main table has two axis. In this case I need use left-right and top-bottom pages. Maybe it will help: [webix pivot demo](http://webix.com/pivot/index.html). [and my comments](http://i.imgur.com/qV4yFU6.png). I'm trying realize scrollable 3rd block and copy solution on 2nd block. Thx.